# preg_replace in PHP - regular expression for NOT condition

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to write a function in PHP using preg_replace where it will replace all those characters which are NOT found in list. Normally we replace where they are found but this one is different.

For example if I have the string:

```
$mystring = "ab2c4d";
```

I can write the following function which will replace all numbers with *:

```
preg_replace("/(\d+)/","*",$mystring);
```

But I want to replace those characters which are neither number nor alphabets from a to z. They could be anything like #$*();~!{}[]|\/.,<>?' e.t.c.

So anything other than numbers and alphabets should be replaced by something else. How do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use a [*negated character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (using `^` at the beginning of the class):

```
/[^\da-z]+/i
```

**Update:** I mean, you *have to* use a negated character class and you *can* use the one I provided but there are others as well ;)

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
preg_replace("/([^a-zA-Z0-9]+)/","*",$mystring);
```

Answer (score 5):

You want to use a [negated "character class"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). The syntax for them is `[^...]`. In your case just `[^\w]` I think.

Answer (score 2):

`\W` matches a non-alpha, non-digit character. The underscore `_` is included in the list of alphanumerics, so it also won't match here.

```
preg_replace("/\W/", "something else", $mystring);
```

should do if you can live with the underscore not being replaced. If you can't, use

```
preg_replace("/[\W_]/", "something else", $mystring);
```

Comment: The second regex will not replace the underscore either. You should use preg_replace("/[\W_]/", "*", $mystring) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `\d`, `\w` and similar in regex all have negative versions, which are simply the upper-case version of the same letter.

So `\w` matches any word character (ie basically alpha-numerics), and therefore `\W` matches anything except a word character, so anything other than an alpha-numeric.

This sounds like what you're after.

For more info, I recommend [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 5.1.0 can use `\p{L}` (Unicode letters) and `\p{N}` (Unicode digits) that is unicode equivalent like `\d` and `\w` for latin

`preg_replace("/[^\p{L}\p{N}]/iu", $replacement_string, $original_string);`

`/iu` modifiers at the end of pattern:

`i (PCRE_CASELESS)`

`u (PCRE_UTF8)`
see more at: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php