# How can i convert characters in PHP?

Tags: php, function, character

I need to convert an example string contains, for example: "ABF965;CDE436;EAF873" in "N;N;N" where all alphanumerics characters must be "N"

Is there any native function to do this?

Comment: I'm sure that this came up while you were researching: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28381345/2943403

Comment: Not exactly....

Comment: The inverse question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4724732/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, replace one or more occurrences of non-semicolon strings.  This is done most simply by using a negated character class.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/KdQYc))

```
$string = "ABF965;CDE436;EAF873";
echo preg_replace('/[^;]+/', 'N', $string);
```

Output:

```
N;N;N
```

More literally, given your sample, an alphanumeric character class with a one-or-more quantifier.

```
echo preg_replace('/[A-Z\d]+/', 'N', $string);
```

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to do just that

Comment: Please always include your failed coding attempt in your Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: @mickmackusa well, that's ironic.

Comment: What is? @Nick ?  I still feel this page should be closed.  I just haven't done it yet because I was with my family yesterday and I just woke up.  Points are uninteresting to me now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), using a regex to convert all sequences of alphanumeric characters to a single `N`:

```
$str = "ABF965;CDE436;EAF873";
echo preg_replace('/[A-Za-z0-9]+/', 'N', $str);
```

Output

```
N;N;N
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ZPpc4)